# SQL Server select with large varchar columns take time to load

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, select, varchar

I am trying to run a simple select query and it has column called instructions with varchar(8000) in the select column list. The table has 
90,000 records and it took my SQL server management studio console to 10 seconds to return and display the full table data

```
SELECT id, name, instructions, etc.... FROM TABLE;
```

however when i remove the instructions from the select list it took only a 1 second to execute and display the result. Can any one please help me to understand the theory behind this

Thanks
Keth

Comment: More data takes longer to read from the database and to load into the application.  This seems pretty fundamental.  It is how computers and networks work.

Comment: There is latency (i.e. time taken) for 90K records with a lot of text to be returned from your database.  If you don't need the instructions, then obviously don't select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some obvious things here that impact the time, and a few more subtle ones around it. The topic of the underlying storage of SQL Server and how it stores / retrieves this data is a book in itself, of which there are many. (I'd personally recommend Kalen Delaney but everyone will have their own preference and I appreciate we should keep away from subjectivity on SO).

- 90k rows of instructions potentially have to be marshalled across your network connection if you were connected from another machine than the server.
- The SSMS console itself, has to display these, which itself takes time.
- depending on the size of what you are reading vs your buffer cache and other queries being executed you could be putting pressure on your cache and generating more physical IO load for the server as a whole.
- As mentioned in comments, more data is being read, but does this mean more is being read from the disk? This one is far more subtle when looked at in detail.

In terms of the disk IO issue, depending on when the instructions are placed in the row and the settings for the column around inlining of data. It might be that the instructions for the row are stored inline with the row, which means no additional disk IO is actually occurring to read them vs not read them, its more a case of whether SQL Server bothers to decode the value from the page in memory.

The varchar(8000) though might not be inline with the rest of the data, it could be on a row_overflow_data page, sometimes referred to as short large object (SLOB), in which case the instruction field itself stores a pointer where the data is stored, and when you read the instructions it causes SQL Server to have to read another entirely random page (and extent) elsewhere on the disk per row.

Depending how / when instructions are added, you could see a huge level of fragmentation / lack of contiguous extents being allocated for these instructions, although depending on the IO subsystem, this may be immaterial to the problem.

There are a lot of unknowns at this point which makes it harder to give anything definitive - you are in the 'it depends' area of the DB, which would need a lot more specifics and investigation to be able to point at a specific cause, vs the more general (and not entirely complete) list above.

As Tim Biegeleisen mentioned, do not read the instructions unless you need to.

Comment: Turn on 'Include Client Statistics' in SSMS and run the two queries. Some of the results will give you some insight into how long the client display part takes, and how much extra data your query is returning, two of the factors listed above